# In a class constructor why is "this required"? why cant I use local variables?

Tags: javascript

I know that local variables dosent work when testing it, but I dont understand the concept. Why does "this" work and local variables does not? a clarification would be great on why I must use this and avoid local variables!
code:

```
 function Person(job, married) {
    var employ = job;
    var status = married;
    }
    var ray = new Person("student", true);
    console.log(ray);
```

Comment: Local variables are destroyed as soon as you leave the scope they are defined in.

Comment: You can use local variables, but they can ONLY be accessed by code that is in the constructor.  They aren't properties of the object created.  If you want to assign a property of the object, you have to reference the object itself `this.someProp = someValue`.  There are design patterns that assign inline methods in the constructor and those methods can access local variables in the constructor, but those variables cannot be accessed directly from outside the constructor.

Comment: Oh are properties essentially global? is that why you use this?

Comment: Variables *do* work. It seems you misunderstand *how* they work, though.

Comment: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html may help you understand about this stuff.  Also this:  http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local variables in your constructor, but they don't automatically become instance variables of your object.  Instead, the way you are using them, they are just temporal local variables, like local variables inside any function definition.

When you do this:

```
 function Person(job, married) {
    var employ = job;
    var status = married;
 }
 var ray = new Person("student", true);
```

Here's what is happening:

1. You define a function named `Person`.
2. In that function, you define two local variables named `employ` and `status`.
3. Those are normal local variables within a function.  They are only visible to code within that function.  These may be useful for some things, but they are not available to any code outside that function.  They are not available to prototyped methods of your object, they are not available to other code outside that function.  In fact, without some sort of reference that creates a closure, they have a limited lifetime and are gone and garbage collected as soon as the `Person` function finishes executing.
4. So, if you intended to create the C++ equivalent of member variables of your object, this did not accomplish that.  The variables are used only for the duration of the `Person()` function and are then disposed of and have no lasting presence.
5. Then, when you execute `var ray = new Person("student", true);`, the following things happen.
6. The `new` causes the system to create a new object, set the value of `this` to point to that new object and then call the `Person` constructor with your two arguments.
7. Your code then creates two local variables which you assign the two arguments to.
8. The `Person()` function then finishes executing and the two local variables are disposed of because the scope in which they were defined is done and is garbage collected.
9. You then assign the newly created object to the variable `ray`.  It is indeed a new object, but it has no custom instance data because nothing was stored in a lasting way.
10. If you then do `console.log(ray)`, you're just going to see an empty object with no instance data other than what the default Object instance has.  Your custom data was not stored anywhere lasting so it's gone now.

If you intend for those two arguments to be saved somewhere lasting as instance data of the object, you have a couple choices.  The more traditional choice is to make them publicly accessible properties of the object.  You would do that like this:

```
 function Person(job, married) {
    this.employ = job;
    this.status = married;
 }
```

Since `this` points to the newly created object, this code assigns the `job` and `married` arguments to properties of the newly created object.  These properties can be accessed either by other methods on the object or by any code outside of the constructor like this:

```
var ray = new Person("student", true);
console.log(ray.employ);   // "student"
console.log(ray.status);   //  true
```

These properties are publicly accessible.

---

There are some interesting things you can do with those local variables that can allow them to persist and be used after the object is created.  To do that, you have to create a closure.  I think of a closure as a function scope that would normally be discarded when the function finishes executing, but because of circumstances, there are still live references within the function scope so the garbage collector does not throw away the function scope when the function finishes executing like it would in a purely stack based language like C++.  Instead, it persists and can be accessed by code after the object has been created.  Here's an example:

```
 function Person(job, married) {
    var employ = job;
    var status = married;

    this.getEmploy = function() {
        return employ;
    }

    this.getStatus = function() {
        return status;
    }
 }
 var ray = new Person("student", true);
 console.log(ray.getEmploy());   // "student"
 console.log(ray.getStatus());   // true
```

Here's the assignment of functions within the constructor has created a closure.  The private local variables `employ` and `status` are still private to within the scope of the Person function.  But, because the `getEmploy` and `getStatus` properties are now publicly exposed and can be called at some time in the future and those functions reference the `employ` and `status` variables, the garbage collector realizes that it can't garbage collect the `employ` and `status` variables so they persist for the lifetime of this newly created `Person` object.

Using terms familiar to other object oriented languages like C++, the `employ` and `status` local variables are giving you some of the features of private instance variables.  Some people call this a hack to fill the void of a feature that Javascript does not offer quite so directly.  But, I don't see it as a hack.  The language offers closures as an enormously useful feature that can be used in so many ways and this is just one way of using a closure to create a benefit, the benefit of private instance data.

Only the publicly assigned properties `getEmploy` and `getStatus` can be accessed by the outside world, but by calling them, we can access the private variables `employ` and `status`.  If we do `console.log(ray)` in this new model, we still won't see `employ` and `status` there because as far as the console is concerned, they still aren't properties of the `ray` object.  But, because of closures, they are uniquely accessible by the methods on the `ray` object.

Further, because a new closure is created each time we call the `Person` constructor, these `employ` and `status` variables are uniquely associated with each new instance of the `Person` object.  They behave and work like private members of the object.

For more examples of this type of structure and some more explanation, see this classic discussion: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

> Why does "this" work and local variables does not?

Unless some sort of lasting closure is created, local variables are temporal.  They last only as long as the containing function is executing and they are then garbage collected.  Just because they are declared inside a function that you are using as a constructor does not make them special.  They are just local variables and have no magic powers beyond just being local variables.

> In a class constructor why is “this required”?
>   a clarification would be great on why I must use this and avoid local
>   variables!

If you want to assign properties to your object, it is `this` that points to your object in the constructor so the only way to assign to a property of your object is to reference the object as `this.someProperty = xxxx`.  That's just how the language works.  All property references in Javascript require an object as the first part of the access.  And, in a constructor, the reference for the newly created object is `this`.  That's how the language was designed.

Those coming from some other object oriented languages might thing you can declare an instance variable of a class and then just use that name all by itself and the interpreter will somehow just know that it's an instance variable name, not a variable name.  That might be true in some other languages.  That is not true in Javascript.  All property references, whether in the constructor, in some method or accessed from the outside as a property on an object must all use an object as the base of the reference.  And, inside the constructor and inside a method, that base is the value of `this`.  So, `this.someProperty` is how you reference that property on the current instance.

Comment: Thank you so so much! and just to make sure, you added "this" in getemploy function because a function is also a variable, thus you want to make it public so you use "this", correct?

Comment: @MatthewFrancis - I wouldn't say it the way you did.  An object property can contain any type of value, a number, a string, a function reference, etc...  In this case, it contains a function reference which makes it a method of the object that you can call.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:

A class is basically an object, right? Well, when you declare a new instance of Person, you're saying "let's create a new object with properties x, y, and z." Using "this" allows you to access the properties for that instance later, while local variables aren't treated as properties for your object.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is called as a constructor (using the `new` keyword), a new object is created (the instance object), prototyped on the object value of the function's prototype property, and the constructor called with its `this` value set to the new instance object just created.

Constructor code can set properties and methods on `this` (the instance object), which is the return value of the constructor call (... unless the constructor explicitly returns some other object).

If variables defined within the constructor are accessed by nested functions which persist after the contructor returns, they will not be garbage collected because they can still be accessed. If they are not accessible after the constructor returns they are essentially discarded and become available for garbage collection.

Object creation is fundamental to JavaScript behavior: Try looking up and  reading about the use of constructor functions.

More about retention of variables in the scope of nested functions after an outer function exits can be found by searching for "closures in JavaScript".